# Javascript array to file on server

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JavaScript client which needs to send data to the server which will then save it as a file.
The client doesn't allow websockets so I've tried using JSON to post it then save it using PHP on the server but as the data on the JavaScript client is a Uint32Array PHP doesn't understand what it is.

This is what I have on the client side

```
var arrayData = new Uint32Array(256);
...
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("data" , JSON.stringify(arrayData));
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open( 'post', 'receive.php', true );
xhr.send(formdata);
```

Then on the server

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['data'])){
    $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
    $fname = mktime() . ".txt";//generates random name

    file_put_contents("upload/" .$fname, data);
}
?>
```

All I get in the text file is 'data' and a PHP error in the logs 
'Use of undefined constant data - assumed 'data'

I've no idea how to get PHP to write this as binary data so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you logged `JSON.stringify(arrayData)` to confirm it is what you think it is before attaching it to `formdata`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
file_put_contents("upload/" .$fname, data);
```

With:

```
file_put_contents("upload/" .$fname, $data);
```

You just forgot a `$` to make `data` a variable, and PHP was searching for a constant named `data`. Not finding it, it assumed (ahhh, PHP!) that you wanted to write `"data"` (a string).

### Added: how to save binary data from your sample

```
// Parse the JSON. $input would be $_POST['data'] for you
$json = json_decode($input);

// This variable contains the string that we'll write to the file
$write = '';

// Loop through the array
for($i = 0; $i < $json->length; $i++) {
    // Append the binary number to $write
    // Note for pack(): 32-bit unsigned integers can be represented with:
    // L -> machine byte order
    // N -> big endian
    // V -> little endian
    $write .= pack('V', $json->{$i});
}

// Then write $write to file
file_put_contents("upload/" .$fname, $write);
```

Comment: Thanks, I no longer get the error but the txt file is empty. If I don't use json_decode I can see the data is there so not sure what's happening.

Comment: @Twisted89 That's probably because you're trying to write an object (json_decode() returns objects by default) to a file. Which format would you like it to be saved in?

Comment: I'd like to save it as binary data - each uint in the array is 4 bytes.

Comment: @Twisted89 can you post an example of the JSON data that's sent to the server? I can write you the code to write binary data, but I need a sample of the input for the PHP script. (also: which byte order? machine byte order, or do you have a preference for endianness?)

Comment: Sure, I believe the data is in little endian, thanks for the help! http://pastebin.com/NvireAiH

Comment: Doesn't matter the endianness of the data that the server receives (as you can see, it's not binary, not even in JSON). I was wondering about the data you want to save.

Comment: The saved data should be the same - little endian.